# Where do javadocs get installed

Tags: installation, java

I installed libguava-lib-doc from the Ubuntu store. But I can't figure out where it installed. Where are the docs, and how can I figure this out in general in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are looking for is in `/usr/share/doc/libguava-java/api/`.

Most (all?) packages install documentation into `/usr/share/doc/packages-name`. If you're ever unsure what was installed by a package, you can run `dpkg -L package-name` to get a list of files that were included.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the files under: `/usr/share/doc/libguava-java/api/`.